# DRY way for setting document.domain from Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cors, cross-domain

I have a Rails app that is using two subdomains which would like to communicate in JavaScript. What would be the most DRY way to effectively set `document.domain = mydomain.com`?

### Conditions that make it less than straight forward

1. This should not be a problem in the development or test environments where the domain is `localhost`.
2. This needs to also be set on certain pages which don't load the main JavaScript file

Condition `1` leads me to think I either want to rely on a Regex that parses the root domain out of `location.host` or do the switching in `erb`.

Condition `2` makes me feel it would be best to write this once and put it in the asset pipeline and include it where necessary.

### Best Potential Solution

Create a file like `domain_setter.js.erb` (contents below), add it to precompile list, and include it in all necessary places (either `\\= require domain_setter` in manifests or `javascript_include_tag 'domain_setter'` for pages without manifests).

```
<%- if Rails.env.production? %>
  document.domain = 'mydomain.com';
<%- end %>
```

## Updated Current Solution

This solution is more dynamic and doesn't require hardcoding a domain. Still not the best but it's working ... *mostly* :-/

```
(function() {
  var domain = /^(?:https?\:\/\/)?.*?([^.]+\.[^.]+?)(?:\:\d+)?$/.exec(location.host);

  if (domain == null) {
    document.domain = 'localhost';
  } else {
    document.domain = domain[1];
  }
})();
```

## tl;dr

What's a DRY way to set mulitple pages' `document.domain` working with Rails?

Comment: To add some background this is to allow two pages on differing subdomains of the same domain able to communicate via JavaScript. i.e. I want `foo.mydomain.com` and `bar.mydomain.com` to communicate which requires both of them to have a lower domain set `mydomain.com`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). This allows javascript to make AJAX `$.get/post` requests across different domains.

Here's a rails library to get you started: https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors#rails

You'll want to set the `origins` property to be `yoursubdomain.herokuapp.com`

Comment: this is closely related to CORS but instead of communicating via Ajax between two different domains, I'm looking for two pages on differing subdomains to communicate via JavaScript. For a small example open a console on any page and enter `window.open('/')`. In the window that just opened enter `window.opener.console.log('back to you original page')` in the console and you'll see that output in the original window's console. This is not possible across subdomains unless their domain is set lower.

Comment: Ah, have you looked at the postmessage API? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: I just took a look at it and it's quite useful especially for communication to other domains. I feel it is slightly more secure and convenient to call arguments directly when both windows have the same `document.domain`.